# declare a vector through decltype

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, type-inference, decltype

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <map>

template <typename T>
auto Copy(T c)
{
    std::vector<decltype(c.begin()->first)> lc;

   //Copying

    return lc;

}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> map;

    Copy(map);


    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I am trying declare a `vector` from the datatype of keys of `map` but I am getting following error -

```
"The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements allocator<const T> is ill-formed."
```

Comment: What do you think the type of `decltype(c.begin()->first)` is, and why?

Comment: Maybe it is simpler to use `typename T::key_type` instead of `decltype(...)`, if you know that `T` will always have a `key_type` member, like `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `decltype(c.begin()->first)` returns a `const int` *(when using **libstdc++** - your example compiles with **libc++**)*.

As your error tells you...

> The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator< const T > is ill-formed.

A possible solution is using [`std::decay_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

```
std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(c.begin()->first)>> lc;
```

This will guarantee that your example works both with **libstdc++** and **libc++**. Alternatively, [`std::remove_const_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) also works in this particular situation.

Here's a [**working example on wandbox.**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/O0EQg02mhjDRFmwc)

Comment: Isn't the key required to be `const`? I'm wondering why there is no problem with `libc++`.

Comment: At some point one should just use the `key_type` typedef instead of this convoluted mess. @user2079303 It's always `const int`. It's just that libc++ happens to be implemented in such a way that `vector<const int>` doesn't blow up quite as easily.

Comment: `decay_t` instead of `remove_const_t`, as your goal is to get a type suitable for storage, and `decay_t` does exactly that?